# Обязательно ли использовать «return» и «void» в этих функциях?

Tags: c

**Пример**:

```
void foo(int number) {
   /* code */

   return;
}
```

Обязательно ли использовать `return` в конце каждой функции или нет?

**Пример 2**:

```
void bar(void) {
    /* code */
}
```

Обязательно ли использовать `void` в списке параметров, если функция `bar` ничего не принимает?

Одни говорят: «да», другие — «нет». Что является правильным для более лучшего понимания кода компилятором, и что вообще правильнее использовать в C?

<sub>Перевод [вот этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326149/is-it-mandatory-to-use-return-and-void-in-the-functions-in-c/29326312#29326312) вопроса с enSO.</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326149/is-it-mandatory-to-use-return-and-void-in-the-functions-in-c/29326312#29326312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно стандарту языка C:

> 10. Особый случай неименованного параметра типа `void` как единственного в списке говорит о том, что у функции нет параметров.
>
> 14. Список идентификаторов определяет только идентификаторы параметров функции. Пустой список в объявлении функции как части определения говорит о том, что у функции нет параметров. Пустой список в объявлении функции, не являющемся частью определения, говорит о том, что информация о количестве и типах параметров не предоставлена.<sup>145)</sup>
>
> — *C11 Standart 6.7.6.3 Function declarations (including prototypes)*

Таким образом, объявление

```
void foo(void);
```

означает, что функция не имеет параметров.

Объявление

```
void foo();
```

означает, что количество и типы параметров функции `foo` неизвестны.

Объявление и в то же время определение

```
void foo() {
    ...
}
```

означает, что у функции `foo` нет параметров.

---

Что касается оператора `return` в функции, которая ничего не возвращает (`void`), то если `return` — это последний оператор в функции, то его обычно опускают. Использование `return` в таком случае может только запутать читающего, поскольку он должен быть уверен, что отсутствие выражения в `return` не является опечаткой.

<sub>Перевод ответа пользователя [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

По поводу что нужно делать в случае возвращаемого значения **void** стандарт говорит, что можно не делать **return;**.

```
A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
whose return type is void.
```

Исключение сделали для функции: `int main()` где можно не делать `return` (по умолчанию возвращается ноль).

При определении функции тип возвращаемого значения нужно всегда указывать, даже если ничего не возвращаете (**void**).

Когда вы определяете функцию с пустыми скобками это не то, что вы НЕ принимаете аргументы, а то, что обработкой списка аргументов вы будуте заниматься лично. И компилятор не будет совать нос в неправильные аргументы клиента и в ваши.

```
// f.h
int f();

// f.c
int f(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;}
```

По этому список аргументов желательно обозначить **void** для того, чтобы не было недоразумений.