# Почему работает такой цикл?

Tags: c, циклы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
int N, sum; // sum - сумма цифр числа
sum = 0; // сначала сумму обнуляем
do { // начало цикла
 printf ( "\nВведите натуральное число:" );
 scanf ( "%d", &N );
 }
while ( N <= 0 ); // условие цикла «пока N <= 0»
while ( N > 0 ) {
 sum += N % 10;
 N /= 10;
 }
printf ( "Сумма цифр этого числа равна %d\n", sum ); 
getch();
}
```

Берём, напр., 5. Результат правильный, 5. (51 выдаёт 6, как и д**о**лжно).

Но ведь... 
 
sum=0+5%10; // =0 
N=5/10 ***// =0, потому что целое/целое, да ещё и записывается в целое***

//Цикл заканчивается, т.к. получаем N=0!>0, имеем sum=0, но компилятор выдаёт:
*Сумма цифр этого числа равна 5*
 Вроде так не должно быть...

Comment: Что за ерунда? `0 + 5 % 10` равно `5`. Откуда вы вдруг взяли, что это равно `0`??? И `int main(void)`, а не `main()`.

Comment: @AnT Ну остаток я и правда не умел брать правильно (см. ниже ответ Ver Nick и мой ему комментарий)... А насчёт int main(void) можно поспорить, потому что, во-первых, до сих пор во всех моих примерах компилятор по этому поводу никак не реагировал, а во-вторых, потому что так объясняется здесь: http://kpolyakov.spb.ru/download/devcpp_1.pdf

Comment: @AnT Вы так говорите, как будто он профессионал. Относитесь спокойно к начинающим.

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук, AnT прав. См. [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889713/Обязательно-ли-использовать-return-и-void-в-этих-функциях)..

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук Во-первых, "компилятор нп реагировал" - это проблема (баг) вашего компилятора. Во-вторых, в книге по ссылке написано много чуши из разряда "это было давно и неправда".

Comment: @AnT Может отчасти Вы и правы, но автор самоучителя ответил мне, что "просто main() мне было удобно для начального обучения школьников, чтобы сразу много непонятных вещей не вводить". Если что, я ему сразу пишу, как видите :) (уже 8 писем за один только вечер - хотя не скажу, что всё это из-за качества его книги).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте разберем все по порядку.
 - Вводим число 5.
 - Число 5 не меньше или равно нулю, значит мы прекращаем цикл.
 - Пока 5 больше нуля, прибавляем к сумме остаток от деления на 10. Вижу вы не очень поняли что такое остаток от деления, потому что остаток от деления 5 на 10 равен 5 (не верите мне, введите в гугле "5 % 10").
 - 5 делим на 10 и записываем в N, получаем 0.
 - Программа выводит результат и прекращает программу.
Остаток от деления 5 на 10 равен 5. Почему? 5 / 10 равен нулю. 5 - 0 = 5. Значит остаток 5! Попробуйте прорешать этот пример на листочке.

Comment: Да, уже заглянул в Вики. Спасибо.

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук Вы новичок?

Comment: В программировании - да. Но выходит, что и в математике, до некоторой степени.